# Definition of smooth functions on arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Let $A$ be an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

We say that $f$ is **smooth** if for each point $p$ in $A$ there exists an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $p$ and a smooth map $g:U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ and $g$ agrees on $A \cap U$.

Now let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$, with $\mathbb{H}^n=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:x^n\ge0 \}$

Let $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function in the above sense.
Let $p\in U \cap \partial\mathbb{H}^n$. Thus there are $\tilde U$ open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a smooth map $g:\tilde U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g$ and $f$ agrees on $U \cap \tilde U$.

> I want to show that the partial derivatives of $f$ at $p$ are determined by their values in Int$\mathbb{H}^n$, and therefore in particular are indipendent of the choice of exstension i.e. of the choice of $g$.

Here is my argument.

$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{f(p+te_i)-f(p)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{g(p+te_i)-g(p)}{t}\qquad [1]$$ beacuse $f(p)=g(p)$ and for sufficient **positive small** $t$ we have $p+te_i \in U \cap \tilde U$ and so $f(p+te_i)=g(p+te_i)$.

Now, since $g$ is smooth at $p$ by hypothesis, we have that the right hand side of the above equation exists, and we have

$$\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{g(p+te_i)-g(p)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0^-}\frac{g(p+te_i)-g(p)}{t}=:\partial_i|_p g$$

**So** I can define $\partial_i|_p f:=\partial_i|_p g$ and this value is indipendent of the choice of $g$ by $[1]$.

So I have shown the claim in the above yellow box.

> Is my argument right? In John M. Lee Textbook Introduction to smooth manifolds, on page 27, he says that **By continuity**, all partial derivatives of $f$ at points of $U\cap \partial\mathbb{H}^n$ are determined by their values in Int$\mathbb{H}^n$, and therefore in particular are indipendent of the choice of exstension.

But it seems I dont'use *the continuity* of any function, so I'm not convinced of having understood the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your argument works. The argument I had in mind was this: Given $p\in \partial \mathbb H^n$, there's a sequence of points $q_j\in \text{Int}\ \mathbb H^n$ such that $q_j\to p$. Because $\partial g/\partial x^i$ is continuous, 
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}(p) 
=
\lim_{j\to \infty} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x^i}(q_j) 
= 
\lim_{j\to \infty} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(q_j),
$$
and this last expression manifestly depends only on the original function $f$.

This argument might be a little simpler, and it has the advantage that it applies to any subset of $\mathbb R^n$ that is the closure of its interior, not just to $\mathbb H^n$. But there's nothing wrong with your argument.

Comment: Thank you very much prof. Lee :)

Comment: @Minato — you’re welcome!